# How to run cmake commands in add_custom_command in order

Tags: cmake

Specifically I'm looking for an example to do what is stated in the cmake documentation for **add_custom_command**:

> If more than one COMMAND is specified they will be executed in order, but not necessarily composed into a stateful shell or batch script. (To run a full script, use the configure_file() command or the file(GENERATE) command to create it, and then specify a COMMAND to launch it.)

A little more detail without bulking this up too much: There's an external program that generates 3 source files that get compiled later. The generation program only updates the timestamp on the files it changes, not all files. So even though my DEPENDS timestamp is newer, it may not need to change 1 of the source files and thus cmake tries to run the code generator each time. I want to touch all the files at the end of the code generation so that ALL their timestamps get updated.

What is the process to run COMMANDS in add_custom_command in order?

EDIT:

This is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${CONFIG_TOOLS_GENERATED_FILES}
    COMMAND if exist ${Application_SOURCE_DIR}/..MCUExpresso/board rmdir ${Application_SOURCE_DIR}/..MCUExpresso/board
    COMMAND
        "${MCU_CONFIG_TOOLS_DIR}/bin/eclipsec.exe" -noSplash 
        -Load ${MEX_FILE}
        -HeadlessTool Pins -ExportSrc "${Application_SOURCE_DIR}/../MCUExpresso" 
        -HeadlessTool Clocks -ExportSrc "${Application_SOURCE_DIR}/../MCUExpresso"
        -HeadlessTool Peripherals -ExportSrc "${Application_SOURCE_DIR}/../MCUExpresso"
    DEPENDS ${MEX_FILE}
    COMMENT "Generating source files using MCU Config Tools"
)
```

There are two issues here - the directory I'm trying to remove (with the generated code) could end up getting deleted after the code generation runs since the commands aren't stateful. Secondly, the directory doesn't actually get deleted - seems like it's a pathing problem with windows...

Comment: How is the order of COMMANDS related to your problem? `an external program that generates 3 source files that get compiled later` is `add_custom_command(OUTPUT file1 file2 file3 COMMAND external_command)`, there is nothing more. `though my DEPENDS timestamp is newer` - please post an [MCVE]. How do you use `DEPENDS`? On what?  ` I want to touch all the files at the end of the code generation so that ALL` - so just `touch file1 file2 file3` them. Does it work? `What is the process ..?` I don't understand the question, what process? `COMMANDS` are run in order. What is unclear in that?

Comment: Fair questions - commands are run in order but they are not necessarily stateful. I take that to mean that some may end up executing before others have completed. If I run it like you say, it seems to work but some files get touched before my code generation runs, and some get touched after. Call my question theoretical then - how could I call these commands synchronously inside add_custom_command.